# How to disable symfony validation of a non mapped field

Tags: symfony

I have an error message "This value is not valid." on a non mapped field. This field is a dropdown with a maximum of 20 items. The user can load more results using ajax. The error happens only when I choose a value loaded using ajax. If I use an element from the original list that shows when the page loads, I don't have this error. I understand that symfony considers it a non valid value because it is not in the original query result, but that's not what I want.
Here is the field definition in the form type:

```
    ->add('clientcustomer', EntityType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Customer',
        'class' => Customer::class,
        'choices' => $this->customerRepository->findClientCustomersForSelect2(),
        'placeholder' => 'New customer',
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
    ))
```

I would like to disable validation for this field.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **FORM EVENTS** see documentation [Form-Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit)

Use **PRE_SUBMIT** event to update your dropdown choices based on form submitted values